# How might I compare this variable so that I can use it in a switch statement?

Tags: c

I just want to allow for string or integer input, but I cannot seem to figure it out, this is what I have so far..

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxL 9182

int main() {
    char menuOption;
    char cmd[10];

// DECLARE FUNCTIONS TO BE USED IN MENU


    float circle() {
        float numbers;
        float calcFloat;


        printf("\n\nYou've selected a circle!\n\n");
        printf("Enter in a value between 1.00 and 1000.00: ");
         scanf("%f%*c",&calcFloat);
        printf("You've entered %f\n", calcFloat);

        numbers = 2*calcFloat*3.14159;

        printf("The circumference of your circle is: %f\n\n\n", numbers);

    }

    float sphere() {
        float sphere;
        float calcSphere;


        printf("\n\nYou've selected a sphere!\n\n");
        printf("Enter in a value between 10.5 and 1024.00: ");
         scanf("%f%*c",&calcSphere);
        printf("You've entered %f\n", calcSphere);

        sphere = (4/3)*calcSphere*calcSphere*calcSphere*3.14159;

        printf("The volume of a sphere with your value is: %.2f\n\n\n", sphere);

    }

    char checkInput(char input) {

        if ((strcmp(input, "0") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "zero") == 0)) {
        return 0;
        }
    }

// END OF FUNCTIONS


// CREATE AND SHOW MENU AND RECEIVE INPUT TO DIRECT TO PROPPER FUNCTION.


    for (;;) {

        printf("Menu: \n" 
        "(0)Circle\n" 
        "(1)Sphere\n" 
        "(2)Palindrome\n" 
        "(3)Shuffle\n" 
        "(4)Quit\n");

        printf("Select your choice!: ");
        scanf("%c", cmd);           

        switch (checkInput(tolower(cmd))) {

            case 0:
                circle();
            break;

            case 1:
                sphere();
            break;
        }
    }

// END OF SWITCH STATEMENT AND MENU
}
```

I want to let people either type 0 or zero into the `scanf` to reduce user error, Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `scanf` but `getline` and write your own code to parse both `0` and `zero` -which I believe is silly.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I would but I have restrictions for this school project..

Comment: I hate it when an assignment or a project requires a feature to be used where it is not necessarily needed just for the sake of course subjects.

Comment: In *C* you cannot use `switch` on strings; you can use it only on integral numerical types (`char`, or `int` etc...) or `enum`-s

Comment: What's with the nested functions?  That's a GCC extension, and not something you should be learning if portability is ever going to be an issue in the code you write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `checkInput` function like this

```
int checkInput(char* input) {
  int i = 0;
  while (i < strlen(input))
    input[i] = tolower(input[i]);

  if ((strcmp(input, "0") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "zero") == 0)) {
    return 0;
  } else if ((strcmp(input, "1") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "one") == 0)) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 4;  // Quit Option
}
```

And in your `main` call like this

```
switch (checkInput(cmd)) {

    case 0:
        circle();
    break;

    case 1:
        sphere();
    break;
}
```

You are accepting a string into variable `cmd`. declare it as a character array like this `char cmd[10];`

Comment: I tried this but I get 2 errors, one on line 50, the if statement in checkInput, and one right on the switch (check) line, both are

`passing argument 1 of 'tolower' (and for the other ) 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]`

Any idea why? Check my original post for updated code

Comment: Argument for tolower function is character. not a pointer to char array. So to convert ZERO to zero you have to call tolower function with each char. got it??

Comment: check my code. i change position of calling tolower function. tolower will only convert a character to lower case(eg: Z to z). not a string

Comment: There's an implicit return at the end of `checkInput()` that doesn't return a value.  Always return a value from every return point!  The switch should have a default to identify 'oops; not coded yet' (or exit, or ...).

Answer (score 1):

The `getline` function will let you store a string into `cmd`.

Then, you can compare your string with `strcmp`

```
if ((strcmp(cmd, "0") == 0) || (strcmp(cmd, "zero") == 0)) {
    circle();
} else if ((strcmp(cmd, "1") == 0) || (strcmp(cmd, "one") == 0)) {
    sphere();
}
```

Comment: I guess I should have stated, I need to use switch statements for this school project :/

Comment: Well, the code above can be used in your `checkInput` function rather than in the main code and keep using your current main code. Anyway, `switch` cannot be used on string in C. Note that `checkInput would then need to accept a `char *` as an input.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to allow for string or integer input

The best way is to use regular expression to verify input

```
    #include <regex.h>

    regex_t checkInteger;
    regex_t checkFloat;

    bool isInteger = false;
    bool isFloat = false

    int reti;
    char input[100];

    // read input from user

    regcomp(&checkInteger, "^[1-9][0-9]*$", 0);
    regcomp(&checkFloat, "^[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+$", 0);

    isInteger = !regexec(&checkInteger, input, 0, NULL, 0);
    isFloat = !regexec(&checkFloat, input, 0, NULL, 0);

    if (isInteger)
    {
            // input is integer
    }
    else if (isFloat)
    {
            // input is float
    }

    regfree(&checkInteger);
    regfree(&checkFloat);
```

Answer (score 0):

solution1:
 as String

```
case "0":
```

as Integer

```
int cmd; // declare cmd as atring




printf("Select your choice!: ");
    scanf("%d", &cmd); 

switch (cmd) {

            case 0:
                circle();
----
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the input into a NUL-terminated string, `cmd`, then

```
switch (((strcmp(cmd, "0") == 0) || (strcmp(cmd, "zero") == 0)) +
        ((strcmp(cmd, "1") == 0) || (strcmp(cmd, "one") == 0)) * 2)
{
case 1:
  circle();
  break;
case 2:
  sphere();
  break;
default:
  // handle the error
  break;
}
```